# SEPA credit transfer from EUR to GBP. What happens? Should there be fees?

Tags: money-transfer, international-transfer, eur-euro, gbp-british-pound, sepa

All my bank accounts are in EUR (I am German) and I needed to transfer 100£ (GBP) to a british bank account to pay a reservation fee. I was provided with an IBAN to that account.

I then converted from EUR to GBP by hand and transferred 117€ (+ a little bit more to compensate for currency flunctuations) via a SEPA credit transfer (UK still participates in SEPA as far as I know, even after the Brexit).

> **Question:** Was this the right procedure? In particular, can I be sure that
>
> - the british account received at least 100£?
> - there are no charges or other inconveniences on the site of the receiver?
>
> My EUR bank account has not seen any additional fees deducted. Is this normal (I expected fees)? Will these fees only be deducted later or do I need to worry that I chose the wrong way to transfer the money?

All in all, I would like to have a better unterstanding of how SEPA credit transfer works between accounts with different currencies. If my approach was wrong, what would be the correct way to transfer the money (without a month of preparation for opening a bank accounts in a different currency).

---

**Update**

It was informed that the british bank account indeed received the right amount (100£). Several weeks later there have still not been deducted any additional fees, and I have just payed 117€ in total.

I can also confirm that it was a SEPA transfer. I just performed another such transfer and after I confirmed it I was informed (by the website) that, since it was not a EUR-EUR transfer, it will be performed as a SEPA transfer.

Comment: Are you sure it was actually SEPA even though the transfer was to a GBP account?

Comment: @GS-ApologisetoMonica I assumed that this is the case when I am using an IBAN. Is it not? Sorry for my naivete!

Comment: I don't think it would be, as I think SEPA is just for EUR-EUR transfers. Maybe you can edit the question to describe exactly what you do know about the transfer?

Comment: SEPA is for EUR payments only. GBP->EUR may fall under SEPA under some/many circumstances, but EUR-GBP almost certainly doesn't (unless you are transferring euro and the beneficiary's bank handles the conversion).

Comment: @GS-ApologisetoMonica Just to point to my update, the website of my bank informed me that this was indeed a SEPA transfer, and surprisingly, they said that it was *because* it was not a EUR-EUR transfer.